# What permit types are viable for IT staff in Greece? (successful experience needed)

Tags: resident-permit, blue-card, greece

could you please share experience with obtaining work permits for IT positions in Greece? We've analyzed all available options like Blue card, Intra-Company Transfer, Public interest permit, Senior level permit (its already eliminated). ITC does not work for our purposes. With BC it's super complicated due to quotas, extremely long processing time and no guarantees of approval. Public interest permit would be good, however, it requires recommendation letter from the Ministry which is hardly possible to obtain.
So at this point we do not see any viable options. This why successful experience of other foreigners would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.